# Jackson 2.5 - JsonMappingException: Missing external type id property

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I have this class with an External Property "contentType":

```
public class ContentEvent implements AbstractMessagingEvent{
    @Valid
    @JsonTypeInfo(include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY, use = NAME, property = "contentType")
    public final ContentValue message;

    public ContentEvent(ContentValue message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public ContentEvent() {
        this(null);
    }

    public static ContentEvent example () {
        return new ContentEvent(HostedFile.example());
    }
}
```

"contentType" can be one of the following:

```
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(SecureFormSubmission.class),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(SecureFormInvitation.class),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(TextPlain.class),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(HostedFile.class),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(ExternalFile.class)
})
public interface ContentValue{
}
```

When I try to deserialize a JSON which is missing the "contentType" field, I get the following error:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Missing external type id property 'contentType'

I tried adding a 'defaultImpl=NoClass.class' and also a defaultImpl=MyOwnCustomClass' and it clears the error, but the result is an object without any 'contentType'.

What I want is in case the 'contentType' field is missing, to use a default.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can annotate the class with `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)`.

Comment: I don't want to ignore the property. I want to make up for a missing property.